# jQuery returns string instead of DOM object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

how can I get DOM object to get some properties of HTML elements with jQuery? For example I want to get dimensions of image after document loaded.

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  var divs = $("#thumbnails_div").children();
  console.log(divs);
  console.log(divs[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbnails_div" class="article_content row">
  <div class="col-2">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Kubota" class="img_thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Kubota" class="img_thumbnail">
  </div>
```

First console.log()gives me DOM object, but the second one only string representation of one of children...but I need real object to iterate throught it (to get dimensions of every image). How can I do it?

There is my result of second console.log():

```
<div class="col-2">
    <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Kubota" class="img_thumbnail">
</div>
```

Comment: `divs` will be a jQuery collection, not a DOM object. `divs[1]` will be an `HTMLDivElement`, not a string, which should be perfectly interactable with

Comment: Tell us what you want to get at and we can tell you what you need to do. For now it is an X/Y problem

Comment: But do you know, how to access children of divs[1]?

Comment: how can I get width of image from my example? divs.eq(1).children().eq(0).width doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example I want to get dimensions of image after document loaded.

In order to achive your result you can search for all **img** elements under the div **thumbnails_div**. For each img you can print the image size using [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
$(function() {
  var divs = $("#thumbnails_div img").each(function (idx, ele) {
    console.log("element index: " + idx, " width:" + ele.width +  " height: " + ele.height);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="thumbnails_div" class="article_content row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000/fff&text=200+x+150" alt="Kubota" class="img_thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff&text=300+x+200" alt="Kubota" class="img_thumbnail">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `console.log()` on a DOM element, the console contains the HTML representation, similar to what's shown in the Elements tab. It's not a string -- you can expand it to see nested elements, you can access attributes, find it in the Elements tab, etc.

If you want something that you can view like a JavaScript object, use `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`.

```js
$(function() {
  var divs = $("#thumbnails_div").children();
  console.log(divs);
  console.dir(divs[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbnails_div" class="article_content row">
  <div class="col-2">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Kubota" class="img_thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Kubota" class="img_thumbnail">
  </div>
```

Comment: But how can I access children of divs[1]?

Comment: `divs.eq(1).children()`

Comment: `divs[1]` is a DOM element, `divs.eq(1)` is a jQuery object.

Comment: Ok and how can I get width of image from my example? divs.eq(1).children().eq(0).width doesn't work...

Comment: It should be `.width()`. Almost everything in jQuery is functions, not properties.

Answer (score 0):

To get to the images *inside* the main div, you can use a multi-part or cascading jQuery selector.

After that you can use the elements inside the resulting collection in 2 ways:

1. If you use `[index]` you get plain DOM elements, for which you can use DOM properties.
2. If you use `.eq(index)` you get a jQuery wrapper for each DOM element, which then supports further jQuery functions such as `.width()` and `.height()`.

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = $("#thumbnails_div .img_thumbnail");
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    console.log("images[" + i + "]:", images[i]);
    console.log("dimensions:", images.eq(i).width() + ' x ' + images.eq(i).height());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="thumbnails_div" class="article_content row">
  <div class="col-2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Kubota" class="img_thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x110" alt="Kubota" class="img_thumbnail">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$(function() {
  var divs = $("#thumbnails_div").children();
  console.log(divs.eq(1));
});
```

That should work for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

We can access the DOM object using JQuery as below.

```
$(element)  // in your case it is $(divs[1])
```

Ex: Get width of the loaded 2nd image as below

```
$(divs[1]).children()[0].clientHeight
```

```js
$(function() {
  var divs = $("#thumbnails_div").children();
console.log('Image Source-->','\n',$(divs[1]).children().attr('src'));
  console.log('Height of rendered Image-->','\n',$(divs[1]).children()[0].clientHeight);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="thumbnails_div" class="article_content row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Kubota" class="img_thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <img src="https://blog.matcharesident.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/iStock-944453634.jpg" alt="Kubota"
            class="img_thumbnail">
    </div>
</div>
```